# Zend Framework 2: Doctrine 2 Query Builder reading table with Many To One Relationship

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a very simple Database Table to store Adverts. Please note that below is the short form of my files and I left the addional fields out.

**advert table**

- id
- advert_title
- advert_text
- advert_user_id

I have created an Advert Entity:

```
class Advert
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="advert_title", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $advertTitle;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="advert_title", type="text", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $advertText; 

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="adverts")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="advert_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $user;

    /** 
 * Set user 
 * 
 * @param \Advert\Entity\User $user 
 * @return Advert 
 */ 
public function setUser(\Advert\Entity\User $user = null) 
{ 
    $this->user = $user; 

    return $this; 
} 

/** 
 * Get user 
 * 
 * @return \Advert\Entity\User 
 */ 
public function getUser() 
{ 
    return $this->user; 
}
```

I am now trying to read out all the adverts with a specific User Id. So a simple:

```
Select * From advert Where advert_user_id = '10'
```

I have therefore created a Repository file with the following query.

```
public function findAdvertsByUser($userID)
{

    $userID = 18; // static for testing

    $query = $this->_em->getRepository($this->getEntityName())->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->where('a.user=:userid' )
        ->setParameter('userid', $userID)
        ->getQuery()->getResult();

// Below to check query and parameters used:    
    $sql=$query->getSQL();
    $parameters=$query->getParameters();
    echo $parameters;
```

The website crashed and I have checked what parameter for user id is used result was: 
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@000000004a00fe4400000000f5af5615

I am too much of a beginner to understand what is going wrong here. Can someone help and give me a hint? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write the full path of entity in the annotation

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="adverts")
```

fixed:

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Advert\Entity\User", inversedBy="adverts")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately this does not fix the problem. The entity itself is working, in another location I can call up the Userdate etc thats fine, the problem is that I can not simply add the User ID to my WHERE clause because it uses Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@000000004a00fe4400000000f5af5615 instead of simply the User ID as the parameter.